# Variables and semantic search in MediaWiki

Tags: templates, mediawiki, semantic-mediawiki

I am in charge of a MediaWiki with Semantic MediaWiki extension installed. Now, I am trying to perform a semantic search this way:

Defining concepts:

```
{{#ifeq:{{#BioDB_value:transcript.swissprot_version}}|||
{{#BioDB_store_table:DB
|Uses DB=http://www.uniprot.org/ SwissProt
|Has Alias={{{transcript.transcript_alias}}}
|Uses DB Version={{{transcript.swissprot_version}}}
|Has Hit=http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/{{{transcript.hit}}}/ {{{transcript.hit}}}
|Has Evalue={{{transcript.evalue}}}
}}}}
```

Semantic search:

```
{{#ask:[[DB::{{FULLPAGENAMEE}}]]|?Has Alias|?Uses DB|?Uses DB Version|?Has Hit|?Has Evalue|mainlabel=-|format=template|template=DBList|introtemplate=DBList_Header|outrotemplate=DBList_Footer}}}}
```

Template:

```
<includeonly>
|-
| {{{1|}}} || [{{{2|}}}] || {{{3|}}} || [{{{4|}}}] || {{{5|}}}
</includeonly>
```

In case of `Uses DB`, it is shown as SwissProt linked to the URL provided. No problem, is what I want. However, this behaviour changes when talking about `Has Hit`. It is shown as `[O34598]`, without any link attached to that. It seems like it only sees the variable `{{{transcript.hit}}}` once, which contains `O34598`. I do not understand why this behaviour change. Whithout variables it works well.

Note: `BioDB_value` and `BioDB_store_table` comes from an extension that allows to obtain values from MySQL.

Comment: What type is Has Hit?
Does `transcript.hit` by any chance contain a space?

Comment: No spaces. It is a string.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem at a public wiki, such as http://smw.referata.com/wiki/Main_Page?